# What will be the correct syntax for DATE_TRUNC() using bigquery sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is related to my previous question

I tried this syntax

```
Group By User, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', TIMESTAMP '2022-09-23 11:00:00 UTC')
```

But im getting an error a valid date part name is required .

Also I tried removing the 'UTC' timezone

```
Group By User, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', TIMESTAMP '2022-09-23 11:00:00')
```

Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want this:

```sql
Group By User, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '2022-09-23 11:00:00', DAY)
```

- [TIMESTAMP_TRUNC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_trunc)